# How to bind a single loading image to a single ajax request

Tags: jquery

Hey I am using jquery ajax but I am having one slight confusion. I have several loading(animated) images that show whenever and ajax request triggers at that specific point. but the problem is,e.g. if I start to enter text in the search area, the loading image beneath that input field displays but also other loading images meant for other areas show!

please assist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTML/JS pls + make jsfiddle to replicate if u can.

Comment: How could you ask that, without any code?